# Uninstall python modules

Tags: python, virtualenv

How to uninstall all python modules that where ocasionally installed. I need this cleanup (as if it is a fresh installation) to start working with virtualenv. Also I want to be sure that there's no intersection. Also I want to make sure that all preinstalled modules, i.e. needed by the OS, are left still.

The OS is Ubuntu 10.4 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the modules using apt-get, you can remove them using apt-get.

If you installed the modules using easy_install, they will be cataloged here: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/easy-install.pth

Here are good instructions for removing easy_install packages.
[stackoverflow - removing easy_install packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install)

When attempting to create pristine environments, it's always best to just start with an actual pristine environment. (fire up a fresh U10.04 VM and take stock of what libraries are installed and then do a diff)